# How to initialize many arrays dynamically in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

Suppose I want to initialize 6 lists of 21 numbers each in a dynamic way, how do I do it?

Like,

```
temporal_id1 = [0, 1, 2, ...., 20]
temporal_id2 = [21, 22, 23, ...., 42]
.    . 
.    .
.    . 
temporal_id6 = [105, 106, ...., 125]
```

What I am doing is a static way. Something like this:

```
temporal_id1 = []
for i in range(0,21):
    temporal_id1.append(i)
temporal_id2 = []
for i in range(21, 42):
    temporal_id2.append(i)
temporal_id3 = []
for i in range(42, 63):
    temporal_id3.append(i)
temporal_id4 = []
for i in range(63, 84):
    temporal_id4.append(i)
temporal_id5 = []
for i in range(84, 105):
    temporal_id5.append(i)
temporal_id6 = []
for i in range(105, 126):
    temporal_id6.append(i)
```

But, this is very naive. And I'm dealing with big data where I have to initialize 107 arrays with 4117 items in each of them.

What I figured is something like this:

```
for i in range (0, 6):
    initialize list temporal_i with values (21 * i , 21 * (i+1)) ------ (?)
```

I just want to know what statement I should write in the (?) line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do variable variables in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham will a dictionary be able to hold up so much data? Like 106 keys and EACH key has 4117 numbers in it? Can you tell me how can I do it with lists? Since my entire code later on depends on them. I can't rewrite it now. I just subsampled the data but now when I realized I have to do it with Big data Im screwed.

Yes, they are just incremental numbers: 
temp_id1 will have 0 to 4116
temp_id2 will have 4117 to 8233..
something like that..

Comment: does each list hold 4117 values?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't get it...How am I using variable variables here? I am just making distinct lists with distinct values each

Comment: @SamarthShah I mean you should replace the pointless `temporal_idN`s with a single list or dictionary of lists. `106 * 4117` is really not that much.

Comment: Why do you _want_ distinct lists? A list of lists or a dict of lists is _much_ easier to work with. Actually, if the values in each list are fixed, there may be more efficient ways to write your code than to build all these lists.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ahh..alrighty, the subsequent code was a lot dependent on those lists. 
Anyways, now that you have suggested me this, can you please tell me how do I initialize a dictionary of such kind?

Comment: @PM2Ring Well, I am working with a Facebook dataset where there are 4117 nodes and time span of 105 days.
At day 0 each node will have ids 0 to 4116..
On day 1, each node will have ids 4117 to something...


Get it? So that's why the first thing that came to my mind was lists. 
But , what's the most optimal way that comes to your mind? 


Please tell. I am not a Python developer but had no choice.

Comment: @SamarthShah this isn't a code-writing service. That being said, zoosuck has already answered showing how to do this.

Comment: Yep,I don't know what's  temporal_id, his question is simple but not about temporal_id, why did not say that first...

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sure it isn't buddy. But I have seen SEVERAL posts where there are similar questions like - "How do I initialize this and that" and it has been answered all the time! My question was just that "How do I initialize something dynamically"? I'm not asking you to write the code for me. So please chill. I'm just asking you to help me with one line!

Comment: @zoosuck  I am working with a Facebook dataset where there are 4117 nodes and time span of 105 days. At day 0 each node will have newly assigned  temporal_ids 0 to 4116.. On day 1, each node will have temporal_ids 4117 to something... So that's why the first thing that came to my mind was lists... I have mentioned temporal_ids in the question itself. I just wanted 106 temporal_id lists - each containing 4117 number, is all! And I wanted my code to be used for other dataset not just the one Im working at!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way use list comprehension:

```
[range(21* i, 21 * (i+1)) for i in range(0,6)]
```

You just need to put the range(21* i, 21 * (i+1)) before the for keyword will works.

Comment: ``list(range(...))`` in Python 3.*

Comment: I use Python2.7... PO didn't emphasize version.

Comment: I'm sorry @zoosuck , can you be more elaborative? But how do I initialize the list temporal_id i? And I use 2.7 only.

Comment: @SamarthShah: `a = [range(21* i, 21 * (i+1)) for i in range(0,6)]` creates a list of lists, with each list containing 21 numbers. Thus `a[0]` is a list of the numbers from 0 to 20, `a[1]` is a list of the numbers from 21 to 41, etc.

Comment: @PM2Ring Very helpful :) Thank you so much. And thanks zoosuck for the answer.

Comment: @SamarthShah: Or you can make a a dict using `a = dict([(i, range(21* i, 21 * (i+1))) for i in range(0,6)])`. Once again, a[0] is a list of the numbers from 0 to 20, etc. You can test these things in the Python interpreter...

Comment: @PM2Ring I just did buddy :) And yes got it. !! Thanks again.

Comment: See [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for info on dictionaries in Python. Also, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict